# HTML import each modules instead of link import

Tags: html

This is my HTML head of electron APP.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="importInfo.info">
</head>
```

And this is importInfo.info File.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HITS</title>
  <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../asset/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="../node_modules/jquery-ui/external/requirejs/require.js"></script> 
  <link href="../asset/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../asset/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="../asset/js/frontLib.script"></script>
```

And I wanted to change this into the HTML below by simply copying and pasting because of this error
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HITS</title>
  <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../asset/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="../node_modules/jquery-ui/external/requirejs/require.js"></script> 
  <link href="../asset/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../asset/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="../asset/js/frontLib.script"></script>
</head>
```

As soon as I changed

[image]

require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () {

```
  return _;
}
```

this error occurs.

What should I do? Can I simply stay with link rel="import"???

It says it is planned to be removed around March 2018 so I'm afraid of that, though time already passed.